# How to manage colors in bdd with CSS

Tags: css, database, seo

In my database I have a table with attribute "color". this color is in hexa and is for displaying a color on the website. But I don't want to put some attributes style="" to my HTML (it's what I did before I heard that style attributes are bad for SEO). So I created classes in my CSS (.black, .red...) But they can't be managed if I create the back office CRUD of the table (except if I edit the file with a function writing new classes inside the style.css file). Is there a solution for that problem ?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Maybe the terms bdd and CRUD could be explained better. And you should remove the [seo] tag; people here hate seo.

Comment: Oh, and inline styles are not as bad as people would have you believe. On the other hand, classes that have the names of colours, with the only purpose to give the elements these colours, hm.

Comment: sorry, bdd is database and crud is 'create, read, uprdate, delete'